# HOw to replace <a href="#" >sometext+url </a> with user defined string using preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, regex

how can i replace

```
<a href="#" >sometext+url </a> with url by using preg_replace
```

i used this function

```
function parse_url($url) {
    $url = preg_replace("#<a\s*[^>]*href=\"#i", "<url>", $url,-1);
    $url = preg_replace("<\a>", "<url>", $url,-1);
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Ignacio the Accepted Answer is wrong. Please dont link people to it. Modern Regex can parse HTML. You just dont want to do it in most cases because it's brittle and parsing HTML is a solved problem.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. You want an anchor element to become a url element? Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function replaceAnchorsWithText($data) {
    /**
     * Had to modify $regex so it could post to the site... so I broke it into 6 parts.
     */
    $regex  = '/(<a\s*'; // Start of anchor tag
    $regex .= '(.*?)\s*'; // Any attributes or spaces that may or may not exist
    $regex .= 'href=[\'"]+?\s*(?P<link>\S+)\s*[\'"]+?'; // Grab the link
    $regex .= '\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*'; // Any attributes or spaces that may or may not exist before closing tag 
    $regex .= '(?P<name>\S+)'; // Grab the name
    $regex .= '\s*<\/a>)/i'; // Any number of spaces between the closing anchor tag (case insensitive)

    if (is_array($data)) {
        // This is what will replace the link (modify to you liking)
        $data = "{$data['name']}({$data['link']})";
    }
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'replaceAnchorsWithText', $data);
}

$input  = 'Test 1: <a href="http: //php.net1">PHP.NET1</a>.<br />';
$input .= 'Test 2: <A name="test" HREF=\'HTTP: //PHP.NET2\' target="_blank">PHP.NET2</A>.<BR />';
$input .= 'Test 3: <a hRef=http: //php.net3>php.net3</a><br />';
$input .= 'This last line had nothing to do with any of this';

echo replaceAnchorsWithText($input).'<hr/>';
?>
```

This function will output:

```
Test 1: PHP.NET1(http: //php.net1).
Test 2: PHP.NET2(HTTP: //PHP.NET2).
Test 3: php.net3 (is still an anchor)
This last line had nothing to do with any of this
```

This code is from the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) itself

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function subanchor($url) {

    return preg_replace("#<a\s*[^>]*href=\"(.*)\".*>(.*)</a>#i", "<url>\\1+\\2</url>", $url);
}

echo subanchor($argv[1]);
?>

$ php subacnchor.php  '<a href="http://hello.com/">trololol</a>' 
<url>http://hello.com/+trololol</url>
```